# Using OpenXml, an cell object sometimes doesnt get in CellFormula property the reference of an Excel cell with C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have some cells on a sheet that I want to check in my C# program.

These cells don't have a formula but a reference (for example: cell B1 "=A1", B2 "=A2", B3="A3"...).

Using OpenXML I manage to store these cells in an object of the Cell class, but I have the problem that sometimes the CellFormula property is not able to store the content of the cell, but the referenced value, that is, in the CellValue property I see the value of B1, which would be the content of A1, but in CellFormula sometimes I see "".

For me it doesn't make sense because all the cells that have a reference have the same syntax, only the numeric part changes.

In fact, if instead of having =A1, I would have "=SheetName!A1" it works fine.

Attached are screenshots of my tests

[Cellformula OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxXBx.png)

[Cellformula with ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt1ln.png)

Comment: What is your question? What would you to receive from the community?

Comment: I was looking for some sense of the bug and I think I finally found it. The problem I have seen that it is in the source Excel (in the image you can see that in InnerXml the reference to the cell is missing) because I have inspected the internal xml of the Excel file and I have been able to see that indeed that information is missing although from Excel it is seen correctly. By editing the box, pressing Enter and saving the document, the internal xml is generated correctly.